# Exclude `?` from URL when submitting empty form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url

When I submit empty form using `GET` method, browser adds `?` symbol to the end of `URL`.

```
http://my-site.com/viewApp/1?
```

My form

```
$('body').append($('<form/>')
  .attr("target","_blank")
  .attr({'action': 'viewApp/'+appId, 'method': 'get', 'id': 'replacer'})
).find('#replacer').submit();
```

I would like to get `URL` without `?` symbol. How can I clean my `URL`?

Comment: If you're sending a GET request why bother building a form and submitting it? `window.location.assign()` will work fine. That way you can also control the exact URL too.

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-to-redirect-to-another-webpage (and http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, how to open it new window?

Comment: `window.open()`